# How to use inline tables inside of equations in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, equations

I'd like to use tables inside equations like this:

[image]

Is it even possible? The example is just a picture with the tables manually added in.

The tables:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{name}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{movie}}\\
\hline
  Jack Nicholson    & Wolf \\
  Dennis Quaid        & Frequency \\ 
  Jack  Black        & The School of Rock \\ 
  Jack Nicholson & The Shining \\
  Morgan Freeman      & Se7en \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{name}} \\
\hline
  Jack Nicholson \\
  Dennis Quaid \\
  Jack  Black \\
  Morgan Freeman \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it exactly as you would expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$
\pi_{\mathrm{name}}\left(\ 
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{name}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{movie}}\\
\hline
  Jack Nicholson    & Wolf \\
  Dennis Quaid        & Frequency \\ 
  Jack  Black        & The School of Rock \\ 
  Jack Nicholson & The Shining \\
  Morgan Freeman      & Se7en \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\ \right)=
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{name}} \\
\hline
  Jack Nicholson \\
  Dennis Quaid \\
  Jack  Black \\
  Morgan Freeman \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind to actually try to put it into the equations. I just assumed it's not possible. Thank you.

Comment: but `\pi_{\mathrm{name}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good catch, i hadn't noticed. I edited it in.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly possible, as the `tabular` environment automatically switches to text mode.However, don't use the `table` environment, which is a float.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \[ \pi_{\text{name}} \\begin{pmatrix}\:
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{name}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{movie}}\\
\hline
  Jack Nicholson & Wolf \\
  Dennis Quaid & Frequency \\
  Jack Black & The School of Rock \\
  Jack Nicholson & The Shining \\
  Morgan Freeman & Se7en \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\:
    \end{pmatrix}
 =
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{name}} \\
\hline
  Jack Nicholson \\
  Dennis Quaid \\
  Jack Black \\
  Morgan Freeman \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]